# scipy weird unexpected behavior curve_fit large data set for sin wave

Tags: pandas, numpy, scipy, curve-fitting, scipy-optimize

For some reason when I am trying to large amount of data to a sin wave it fails and fits it to a horizontal line. Can somebody explain?

Minimal working code:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy import optimize
# Seed the random number generator for reproducibility
import pandas

np.random.seed(0)

# Here it work as expected
# x_data = np.linspace(-5, 5, num=50)
# y_data = 2.9 * np.sin(1.05 * x_data + 2) + 250 + np.random.normal(size=50)

# With this data it breaks
x_data = np.linspace(0, 2500, num=2500)
y_data = -100 * np.sin(0.01 * x_data + 1) + 250 + np.random.normal(size=2500)

# And plot it

plt.figure(figsize=(6, 4))
plt.scatter(x_data, y_data)


def test_func(x, a, b, c, d):
    return a * np.sin(b * x + c) + d

# Used to fit the correct function
# params, params_covariance = optimize.curve_fit(test_func, x_data, y_data)

# making some guesses
params, params_covariance = optimize.curve_fit(test_func, x_data, y_data,
                                               p0=[-80, 3, 0, 260])

print(params)
plt.figure(figsize=(6, 4))
plt.scatter(x_data, y_data, label='Data')
plt.plot(x_data, test_func(x_data, *params),
         label='Fitted function')

plt.legend(loc='best')

plt.show()
```

[image: This is the function with a lot of data and fitted incorrectly]

[image: This is the function with little data and fitted correctly]

Does anybody know, how to fix this issue. Should I use a different fitting method not least square? Or should I reduce the number of data points?

Comment: Did you try with `lmfit`? https://lmfit.github.io/lmfit-py/builtin_models.html?highlight=custom#lmfit.models.ExpressionModel

Comment: your fit *does* work, you just need better starting values for your data set that doesn't fit well.  Your commented-out example doesn't even have initial values at all.  `curve_fit` is dangerously wrong and (purposefully - yes, purposefully!) misleading you that not giving initial values is ever reasonable.  It is not.  Initial values are ALWAYS REQUIRED and they should be a decent approximation of the expected values and give a non-trivial result for the function you are modeling.  So, in short: guess better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given your data, you can use the more robust `lmfit` instead of `scipy`.

In particular, you can use `SineModel` (see [here](https://lmfit.github.io/lmfit-py/builtin_models.html?highlight=custom#lmfit.models.SineModel) for details).

`SineModel` in `lmfit` is not for "shifted" sine waves, but you can easily deal with the shift doing

```
y_data_offset = y_data.mean()
y_transformed = y_data - y_data_offset
plt.scatter(x_data, y_transformed)
plt.axhline(0, color='r')
```

[image]

Now you can fit to sine wave

```
from lmfit.models import SineModel

mod = SineModel()

pars = mod.guess(y_transformed, x=x_data)
out = mod.fit(y_transformed, pars, x=x_data)
```

you can inspect results with `print(out.fit_report())` and plot results with

```
plt.plot(x_data, y_data, lw=7, color='C1')
plt.plot(x_data, out.best_fit+y_data_offset, color='k')
#           we add the offset ^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

[image]

or with the builtin plot method `out.plot_fit()`, see [here](https://lmfit.github.io/lmfit-py/model.html?highlight=fit#lmfit.model.ModelResult.plot_fit) for details.

Note that in `SineModel` all parameters "are constrained to be non-negative", so your defined negative amplitude (-100) will be positive (+100) in the parameters fit results. So the phase too won't be 1 but π+1 (PS: they call `shift` the phase)

```
print(out.best_values)

{'amplitude': 99.99631403054289,
 'frequency': 0.010001193681616227,
 'shift': 4.1400215410836605}
```